# Pandasにおいて、IDでグループ化してからデータ削除を行いたい

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasで以下のdfを処理しようとしています。A列（ID）が同じデータのうち、E列において、後ろに0がない1の値が不要であり、削除したいです。つまり、13、14行目はA列（ID）が3であり、ID＝3において後ろにE列の値に0がないので削除したいです。（21行目のID＝5においても同様）
初心者にもわかりやすい方法があればご教示いただけますでしょうか。

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1   0   0   0   1   116
2   1   0.8 0.8 2.2 0   0
3   1   0.2 0.2 4.4 0   0
4   1   0.8 0.4 0.4 0   0
5   1   0.5 0.7 3.8 0   0
6   2   1   1   8.9 1   116
7   2   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
8   2   2   2   8.7 0   0
9   3   3   3   5.  0   0
10  3   4.5 4.5 2.2 1   116
11  3   6.0 6.5 0.8 0   0
12  3   8   8   0.3 0   0
13  3   5.3 0   0   1   116   #IDが3、E列の値が1で後ろにE列0がないので削除
14  3   0   0   0   1   116 　#IDが3、E列の値が1で後ろにE列0がないので削除
15  4   0.8 0.8 1.1 1   116
16  4   0.2 0.5 3.4 0   0
17  4   0.4 0.8 3.2 1   116   #IDが4、E列の値が1だが、後ろの18行目はIDが4、E列1なので削除しない
18  4   0.7 0.5 3.0 0   0
19  5   1   1   1.5 1   116
20  5   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
21  5   2   2   7.9 1   116   #IDが5、E列の値が1で後ろにE列0がないので削除
22  6   2   2   7.9 1   116
・
・
・
```

以下が目標とするdfです。

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1   0   0   0   1   116
2   1   0.8 0.8 2.2 0   0
3   1   0.2 0.2 4.4 0   0
4   1   0.8 0.4 0.4 0   0
5   1   0.5 0.7 3.8 0   0
6   2   1   1   8.9 1   116
7   2   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
8   2   2   2   8.7 0   0
9   3   3   3   5.  0   0
10  3   4.5 4.5 2.2 1   116
11  3   6.0 6.5 0.8 0   0
12  3   8   8   0.3 0   0
13  4   0.8 0.8 1.1 1   116
14  4   0.2 0.5 3.4 0   0
15  4   0.4 0.8 3.2 1   116
16  4   0.7 0.5 3.0 0   0
17  5   1   1   1.5 1   116
18  5   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
19  6   2   2   7.9 1   116
・
・
・
```

Comment: 例えば元データの23行目以後が省略されていますが、22行目のように`A`が`6`で`E`が`1`の行が1行だけの場合(省略された次行の`A`が`7`)の場合はどうしますか？ あるいはそういうデータは存在しない？ それから17行目コメントの後ろの1と21行目のコメント内の0と1は逆のようですが。

Comment: IDが1行だけのデータは存在いたしません。基本的にIDごとに2行以上からなるデータで、単にE列において、後ろに0がない1の行だけを削除したいです。また、17行目に関して、訂正いたしました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前回同様、元のデータが`df`に入っている、かつ23行目に`23  6   2   2   7.9 0   0`のデータがあるとして、以下のように出来るでしょう。(追記：インデックスの扱いを修正)

```
df.index -= 1  ## いったんインデックスを0オリジンに設定しておく
droprows = []
grouped = df.groupby('A')
for i, dfw in grouped:
    rindex = sorted(dfw.index, reverse=True) ## グループ毎のインデックスを降順でソート
    for j in rindex:
        if df.iloc[j, 4] == 1:  ## 元のdfからデータ取得して'E'が1なら削除リストに追加
            droprows.append(j)
        else:                   ## 'E'が0ならこのグループの処理を終了して次のグループへ
            break

droprows.sort() ## 削除リストを昇順でソートしておく

df.drop(index=droprows, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.index += 1  ## インデックスを1オリジンに戻す
```